# Aafter Upgrade to Webpack 5 yarn start failing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server

I have upgaded m project Node version with all dependancies now I am attempting upgrade to Webpack 4 to Webpack 5. However when I run npm start I get this error. Strange thing is I don't use applyWebpackOptionsDefaults anywhere and after scouring the node_modules I see that it is used in the webpack lib quite a few times. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Is there a package I haven't updated? What am I missing?

Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.

- options has an unknown property 'before'. These properties are valid:
  object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }

Here is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nakamonsta",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "solidity:test": "truffle test",
    "solidity:lint": "solhint \"contracts/**/*.sol\"",
    "web:lint": "yarn eslint src/",
    "web:build": "truffle compile && node scripts/build.js",
    "web:test": "jest --env=jsdom",
    "migrate": "truffle migrate",
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "lint": "yarn solidity:lint && yarn web:lint",
    "clean": "node scripts/clean_build.js",
    "prepopulate": "node scripts/prepopulate.js",
    "populate": "truffle exec scripts/populate.js",
    "fullstart": "yarn clean && yarn migrate && yarn populate && yarn start",
    "test": "yarn solidity:test && yarn web:test"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "yarn lint"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "babel-core": "6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "27.3.1",
    "babel-loader": "8.2.3",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^10.0.0",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.0",
    "chrono-node": "^2.3.2",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "drizzle": "^1.4.0",
    "drizzle-react": "^1.3.0",
    "drizzle-react-components": "^1.4.0",
    "eth-block-tracker-es5": "^2.3.2",
    "ethereumjs-util": "^7.1.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "fs-extra": "10.0.0",
    "ganache-cli": "^6.12.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "raf": "^3.4.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dev-utils": "^11.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router": "^6.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-auth-wrapper": "^3.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.0",
    "scrypt": "github:barrysteyn/node-scrypt#fb60a8d3c158fe115a624b5ffa7480f3a24b03fb",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "truffle-contract": "^3.0.6",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^0.0.6",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "web3": "^1.6.0",
    "webpack": "5.52.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@webpack-cli/generators": "^2.4.1",
    "eslint": "8.2.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "8.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.27.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "jest": "27.3.1",
    "openzeppelin-solidity": "3.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "solhint": "^3.3.6",
    "underscore": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node",
      "mjs"
    ]
  }
}
```

webpack.config.dev.js file:

```
"use strict";

const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require("case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin");
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require("react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin");
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require("react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin");
const eslintFormatter = require("react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter");
const getClientEnvironment = require("./env");
const paths = require("./paths");

// Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
// In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config easier.
const publicPath = "/";
// `publicUrl` is just like `publicPath`, but we will provide it to our app
// as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
// Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_PATH%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_PATH%xyz.
const publicUrl = "";
// Get environment variables to inject into our app.
const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

// This is the development configuration.
// It is focused on developer experience and fast rebuilds.
// The production configuration is different and lives in a separate file.
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  // You may want 'eval' instead if you prefer to see the compiled output in DevTools.
  // See the discussion in https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/343.
  devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
  // These are the "entry points" to our application.
  // This means they will be the "root" imports that are included in JS bundle.
  // The first two entry points enable "hot" CSS and auto-refreshes for JS.
  entry: [
    // We ship a few polyfills by default:
    require.resolve("./polyfills"),
    // Include an alternative client for WebpackDevServer. A client's job is to
    // connect to WebpackDevServer by a socket and get notified about changes.
    // When you save a file, the client will either apply hot updates (in case
    // of CSS changes), or refresh the page (in case of JS changes). When you
    // make a syntax error, this client will display a syntax error overlay.
    // Note: instead of the default WebpackDevServer client, we use a custom one
    // to bring better experience for Create React App users. You can replace
    // the line below with these two lines if you prefer the stock client:
    // require.resolve('webpack-dev-server/client') + '?/',
    // require.resolve('webpack/hot/dev-server'),
    require.resolve("react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient"),
    // Finally, this is your app's code:
    paths.appIndexJs
    // We include the app code last so that if there is a runtime error during
    // initialization, it doesn't blow up the WebpackDevServer client, and
    // changing JS code would still trigger a refresh.
  ],
  output: {
    // The build folder.
    path: paths.appBuild,
    // Add /* filename */ comments to generated require()s in the output.
    pathinfo: true,
    // This does not produce a real file. It's just the virtual path that is
    // served by WebpackDevServer in development. This is the JS bundle
    // containing code from all our entry points, and the Webpack runtime.
    filename: "static/js/bundle.js",
    // There are also additional JS chunk files if you use code splitting.
    chunkFilename: "static/js/[name].chunk.js",
    // This is the URL that app is served from. We use "/" in development.
    publicPath: publicPath,
    // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location (format as URL on Windows)
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
      path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, "/")
  },
  resolve: {
    // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
    // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
    // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/253
    modules: ["node_modules", paths.appNodeModules].concat(
      // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
    ),
    // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
    // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
    // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/290
    // `web` extension prefixes have been added for better support
    // for React Native Web.
    extensions: [".web.js", ".mjs", ".js", ".json", ".web.jsx", ".jsx"],
    alias: {
      // Support React Native Web
      // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
      "react-native": "react-native-web"
    }
  },
  module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,
    rules: [
      // TODO: Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
      // We are waiting for https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2176.
      // { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

      // First, run the linter.
      // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
      {
        // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
        // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
        // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
        oneOf: [
          // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
          // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
          // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
          {
            test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
            loader: require.resolve("url-loader"),
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]"
            }
          },
          // Process JS with Babel.
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
            options: {
              // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
              // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
              // directory for faster rebuilds.
              cacheDirectory: true
            }
          },
          // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
          // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
          // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
          // In production, we use a plugin to extract that CSS to a file, but
          // in development "style" loader enables hot editing of CSS.
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              require.resolve("style-loader"),
              {
                loader: require.resolve("css-loader"),
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1
                }
              },
              {
                loader: require.resolve("postcss-loader"),
                options: {
                  // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                  // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                  ident: "postcss",
                  plugins: () => [
                    require("postcss-flexbugs-fixes"),
                    autoprefixer({
/*                      browsers: [
                        ">1%",
                        "last 4 versions",
                        "Firefox ESR",
                        "not ie < 9" // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                      ],*/
                      flexbox: "no-2009"
                    })
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
          // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
          // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
          // This loader doesn't use a "test" so it will catch all modules
          // that fall through the other loaders.
          {
            // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
            // its runtime that would otherwise processed through "file" loader.
            // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
            // by webpacks internal loaders.
            exclude: [/\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
            loader: require.resolve("file-loader"),
            options: {
              name: "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
      // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
      // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml
    }),
    // Makes some environment variables available in index.html.
    // The public URL is available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
    // <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    // In development, this will be an empty string.
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw),
    // Add module names to factory functions so they appear in browser profiler.
    //new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
    // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    // This is necessary to emit hot updates (currently CSS only):
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // Watcher doesn't work well if you mistype casing in a path so we use
    // a plugin that prints an error when you attempt to do this.
    // See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/240
    new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
    // If you require a missing module and then `npm install` it, you still have
    // to restart the development server for Webpack to discover it. This plugin
    // makes the discovery automatic so you don't have to restart.
    // See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/186
    new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),
    // Moment.js is an extremely popular library that bundles large locale files
    // by default due to how Webpack interprets its code. This is a practical
    // solution that requires the user to opt into importing specific locales.
    // https://github.com/jmblog/how-to-optimize-momentjs-with-webpack
    // You can remove this if you don't use Moment.js:
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)
  ],
  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    dgram: "empty",
    fs: "empty",
    net: "empty",
    tls: "empty",
    child_process: "empty"
  },
  // Turn off performance hints during development because we don't do any
  // splitting or minification in interest of speed. These warnings become
  // cumbersome.
  performance: {
    hints: false
  }
};
```

webpackDevServer.config.js

```
'use strict';

const errorOverlayMiddleware = require('react-dev-utils/errorOverlayMiddleware');
const noopServiceWorkerMiddleware = require('react-dev-utils/noopServiceWorkerMiddleware');
const ignoredFiles = require('react-dev-utils/ignoredFiles');
const config = require('./webpack.config.dev');
const paths = require('./paths');

const protocol = process.env.HTTPS === 'true' ? 'https' : 'http';
const host = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';

module.exports = function(proxy, allowedHost) {
  return {
    
    disableHostCheck:
      !proxy || process.env.DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK === 'true',
    // Enable gzip compression of generated files.
    compress: true,
   
    contentBase: paths.appPublic,
   
    hot: true,
   
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
   
    quiet: true,
    
    watchOptions: {
      ignored: ignoredFiles(paths.appSrc),
    },
    // Enable HTTPS if the HTTPS environment variable is set to 'true'
    https: protocol === 'https',
    host: host,
    overlay: false,
    historyApiFallback: {
      
      disableDotRule: true,
    },
    public: allowedHost,
    proxy,
    before(app) {
      
      
      app.use(noopServiceWorkerMiddleware());
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: Did you read this https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/? Did you upgrade all your loaders to the latest versions?

Comment: @morganney how to do that?

Comment: @morganney I have Used above article and loaders are at the latest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uninstall webpack and install it with latest version again.Then followed  webpack.js.org/migrate/5 .Updated all loader withhh configration provided in the article.